# How to extract mapped ports from `docker ps`'s output

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I'm trying to get all the ports used by a Docker container with this command:

```
sudo docker ps | tail -n1
29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751
```

When I ran it in terminal I got I want.

```
$ sudo docker ps | tail -n1 | awk '{print $12}'
0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp,
```

But I need all the mapped ports. Is it possible to make a shell script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
paramnum=$(sudo docker ps | grep $lasttimestamp | wc -w);
text=$(sudo docker ps | tail -n1);
begin=($paramnum-4);
end=($paramnum-1);
for (( i=$end; i>=$begin; i--))
do
  t="awk '{print $"$i"}'";
  eval "echo $text | $t";
done
```

I've been hanging around for few hours. Please help, or suggest how to get an output like below.

```
0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp
0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp,
0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp,
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
sudo docker ps | \
tail -n 1 | \
perl -lae '$,="\n";foreach(@F){/tcp,?$/&&push(@x,$_)};print(@x)'
```

- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `$,="\n"`: sets the output field separator to `\n`;
- `foreach(@F){/tcp,?$/&&push(@x,$_)}`: for each element of `@F`, if the element ends with `tcp` followed by an optional `,` adds the element at the end of `@x`;
- `print(@x)`: prints each element of `@x` followed by the output field separator;

```
% cat in
29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          foo/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751
29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751
29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751
% tail -n 1 in | perl -lae '$,="\n";foreach(@F){/tcp,?$/&&push(@x,$_)};print(@x)'
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,
0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp
```

Comment: I have neither known Perl anymore but I really appreciate to you for this. How to try this code with in "docker ps".

Comment: @R.Chonpisit The first line I wrote is meant to be copy-pasted-run on the terminal, the remainder is just an explanation of what it  does: `sudo docker ps | perl -lane '$next=<>&&redo;$,="\n";foreach(@F){/tcp,?$/&&push(@list, $_)};print(@list);last'`

Comment: @R.Chonpisit The previous version was wrong, see the update. This should work fine: `sudo docker ps | tail -n 1 | perl -lae '$,="\n";foreach(@F){/tcp,?$/&&push(@x,$_)};print(@x)'`

Answer (score 25):

According to the docker man pages you could try this:

```
sudo docker ps --format "{{.Ports}}"
```

or if you also need ID:

```
sudo docker ps --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Ports}}"
```

It is not mentioned in the documentation, but to format output you have to use `{{}}`.

Quote from `man docker-ps`:

```
   --format="TEMPLATE"
      Pretty-print containers using a Go template.
      Valid placeholders:
         .ID - Container ID
         .Image - Image ID
         .Command - Quoted command
         .CreatedAt - Time when the container was created.
         .RunningFor - Elapsed time since the container was started.
         .Ports - Exposed ports.
         .Status - Container status.
         .Size - Container disk size.
         .Labels - All labels asigned to the container.
         .Label - Value of a specific label for this container. For example .Label "com.docker.swarm.cpu"
```

---

### Docker 1.10.3

Nowadays, there are a few useful notes about `{{}}` braces in `man docker-ps`:

```
   --format="TEMPLATE"
      Pretty-print containers using a Go template.
      Valid placeholders:
         .ID - Container ID
         .Image - Image ID
         .Command - Quoted command
         .CreatedAt - Time when the container was created.
         .RunningFor - Elapsed time since the container was started.
         .Ports - Exposed ports.
         .Status - Container status.
         .Size - Container disk size.
         .Labels - All labels assigned to the container.
         .Label - Value of a specific label for this container. 
         For example {{.Label "com.docker.swarm.cpu"}}

Display containers with their commands
              # docker ps --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Command}}"
              a87ecb4f327c: /bin/sh -c #(nop) MA
              01946d9d34d8: /bin/sh -c #(nop) MA
              c1d3b0166030: /bin/sh -c yum -y up
              41d50ecd2f57: /bin/sh -c #(nop) MA

Display containers with their labels in a table
              # docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Labels}}"
              CONTAINER ID        LABELS
              a87ecb4f327c        com.docker.swarm.node=ubuntu,com.docker.swarm.storage=ssd
              01946d9d34d8
              c1d3b0166030        com.docker.swarm.node=debian,com.docker.swarm.cpu=6
              41d50ecd2f57        com.docker.swarm.node=fedora,com.docker.swarm.cpu=3,com.docker.swarm.storage=ssd

Display containers with their node label in a table
              # docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{(.Label "com.docker.swarm.node")}}'
              CONTAINER ID        NODE
              a87ecb4f327c        ubuntu
              01946d9d34d8
              c1d3b0166030        debian
              41d50ecd2f57        fedora
```

Comment: hellingly yes​​

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` with the field delimiter `{2,}`. Why `{2,}`? the output of `ps` uses **more than one space** as separator between the columns. Means, we can use this as separator for the `awk` command.

`awk -F" {2,}" '{print $6}'`

or for your `ps` command

```
sudo docker ps | tail -n1 | awk -F" {2,}" '{print $6}'
```

or without `tail`

```
sudo docker ps | awk -F" {2,}" 'END {print $6}'
```

---

*Sample output*

```
% <<<'29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751' \
awk -F" {2,}" '{print $6}'
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp
```

or

```
% <<<'29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   "/bin/bash"         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751' \
    awk -F" {2,}" '{print $6}' |\
    tr ' ' '\n'
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,
0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp,
0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp
```

Comment: I try your code on this way.
echo "29ba3137f3e2        java8/local:latest   /bin/bash         3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32783->5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32782->10523/tcp   DEMO-20151118124751" | awk -F" {2,}" '{print $6}'
but it produced nothing.

Comment: Sure not, `ps` has another output.

Answer (score 2):

docker ps -q | xargs -n1 docker port